# $sn: W\rightarrow \{1,-1\},sn(\sigma)=(-1)^{l(\sigma)}$ is a homomorphism

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems, weyl-group

> Define $sn: W\rightarrow \{1,-1\}$ by $sn(\sigma)=(-1)^{l(\sigma)}.$ Prove that $sn$ is a homomorphism (where $W$ is the Weyl group and $l$ is the length function of reduced expressions in $W$).

Given $\sigma_1,\sigma_2\in W$, write $\sigma_1=\sigma_{\alpha_1}\cdots\sigma_{\alpha_t}$ and $\sigma_2=\sigma_{\beta_1}\cdots\sigma_{\beta_t}$ reduced, for $\alpha_i,\beta_i\in \Delta$ (not necessarly distinct).  Then the homomorphism condition ($sn(\sigma_1\sigma_2)=sn(\sigma_1)sn(\sigma_2) )$ would follow if we could show that  $l(\sigma_1\sigma_2)=l(\sigma_1)+l(\sigma_2)$. But i can't see how this is true. For me i can only see that $\leq$, not equality. Any insights on how to prove this statement? Trying to write $\sigma_1\sigma_2$ using the above identites didn't help; and also the fact that $l(\sigma)=n(\sigma)$ didn't help too.

Comment: Certainly, the length is not additive like that (or the group could never be finite). But note that you just need the length of the product to have the same parity as the sum of the lengths. This is because the Weyl group is a Coxeter group, so cancellation always happens in pairs.

Comment: Yes! that's what i was thinking exactly now... ok, i'll try to formalize that

Comment: What definition of Weyl group are you using?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez the definition given at humphreys's: the group generated by $\sigma_\alpha, \alpha\in \Phi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have $W$ defined as a subgroup of $GL(V)$, you can simply consider the determinant map $\det:W\to\mathbb R$. This is a homomorphism, of course, and you can trivially show that on each reflection it takes the value $-1$. It follows, of course, that for all $\sigma\in W$ we have $\det\sigma=(-1)^{l(\sigma)}$. As an immediate consequence of this, your map $\operatorname{sn}$ is a homomorphism, since it coincides with $\det$.